# How does one clear the Rhythmbox music library database?

Tags: rhythmbox

How do I wipe the music database of Rhythmbox? I have imported lots of music into Rhythmbox. Now I want Rhythmbox to forget everything that I've imported.

Comment: Related https://answers.launchpad.net/rhythmbox/+question/7645

Comment: Incredible that after all this time this feature is still missing from Rhythmbox!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Close Rhythmbox and delete the Rhythmbox database in `~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml`.

If you also want Rhythmbox to forget your library paths (the directories where it automatically looks for music), then you need to delete them from dconf:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.rhythmbox.rhythmdb locations "['file:///dev/null']"
```

You can then set new paths in the Rhythmbox GUI, under `Edit -> Preferences -> Music`.

(Note that

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.rhythmbox.rhythmdb locations
```

does not work correctly, since then Rhythmbox tries to be "smart" and uses your home directory as a default value.  Using `/dev/null` above prevents this; alternatively you could directly set the library paths using `gsettings set`).

Comment: What is the name of the database file?

Comment: @N.N.: I am not 100% sure (I use banshee). I will try to find it and update my answer.

Comment: I would appreciate that. Note that it was not me that downvoted your answer. Your answer needs more details to be a good one but does not deserve a downvote.

Comment: @N.N.: I updated my answer and sorry for the hilarious spelling mistake there haha!

Comment: Hi, if Roland Taylor's answer is correct, and it is, then the Rhythmbox database file's name is rhythmdb.xml. Yes?

Comment: @grahammechanical: yes.

Comment: @RolandTaylor Your answer is correct for my system except for one tiny detail. The path should be `.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml` (the directory is called "rhythmbox" and not "Rhythmbox").

Comment: Warning: Deleting this file will also delete your radio station data!  If you really want to do this, back it up elsewhere first, and then re-add the radio station entries.  As I believe these should be separated, I've filed a but about this.  Please mark this bug as affecting you (if it bothers you as much as it does me): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/951977

Comment: This only half worked for me: I deleted the file multiple times but on each restart Rhythmbox remembered my library paths.  Then I purged and reinstalled Rhythmbox.  After that it still magically remembered the last path I had added, but had forgotten the ones I wanted to erase.  Not sure how it's keeping the paths when I erase the .xml file???

Comment: @ntc2 it's probably stored in in dconf.

Comment: @RolandiXor Yes, I think that's it! I'll add the details to your answer.