# How do I select which files are shown in Rhythmbox?

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox

I have Ubuntu 12.04, and it came with Rhythmbox.  Now I want to put some music on my computer, so I opened Rhythmbox, and it's displaying a long list of files from various places on my computer.  I'm not sure how it decided which files to list - some of them aren't even audio files.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzcHV.jpg

I tried going to Edit -> Preferences -> Music -> Library Location, and it said there were multiple locations and wouldn't tell me what they were, so I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189265/how-do-i-edit-the-list-of-music-library-locations-in-rhythmbox) and disabled the Ubuntu One plugin and set the library location to a single folder (which currently exists and is empty).  This had no effect on what files Rhythmbox listed.  Restarting Rhythmbox and restarting my computer also had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

i managed to solve this by just removing everything from rhythmbox, then it only loaded the music in the location folder.
so in rhythmbox try

- select all the items in rhythmbox, right click and select remove
- Then add all the music that you want into the location folder

Comment: Okay, that seems to have solved the problem, but ... how did it decide to show those files in the first place, and where is it keeping the information that tells it which files to show or not show?

Comment: The information of the files is stored in a an xml file in ~/.local/share/rhythmebox. its explaned in this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/56328/how-does-one-clear-the-rhythmbox-music-library-database